# setup apache and php on Mint

Tags: php, apache, linux-mint

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I have done and created a test page test.php but the browser doesn't show any information

test.php content

```
<!--?php
phpinfo();
?-->
```

But the apache alone works (the browser loads the http://localhost/ just fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Your current code seems like a malformed HTML comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, PHP open and close tags are `<?php` and `?>`. Instead of php tags, you have a html comment (`<!--` and `-->`). Your `test.php` should look like this:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```